# Selected option in a select tag in a php from

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to apply the selected option in this select tag so when I click the submit button and the page is called itself I will see selected the option that I got selected before pressing the submit button.

```
<form method="get" action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <select name="cities" id="cities">
        <?php
        foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM CITY')as $city)
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $city['Name'] . '">' . $city['Name'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Show">
    </form>
```

Comment: Inside the loop, check if `$city['Name']` matches `$_GET['cities']`, and if so, add the `selected` attribute to the option tag.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.